# I want to change the sample rate from my input node from 44100 to 8000

Tags: audio, swift3, buffer, avfoundation, xcode8

I want to read the buffer from my microphone into an array, with 44.1khz its working fine but with the sample rate 8khz it comes to an error

```
ERROR:    >avae> AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:884: SetOutputFormat: required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate
2016-11-26 19:32:40.674 Atem[5800:1168274] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'
```

with my following code :

```
 var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    func setup() {

    print("new")
    let input = engine.inputNode!
    let bus = 0

    let mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()
    engine.attach(mixer)

    engine.connect(input, to: mixer, format: input.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
    //pcmFormatFloat64 -- pcmFormatFloat32
    print(engine.isRunning)
    let fmt = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 12000, channels: 1, interleaved: true)

    do {
        try engine.start()


     print(engine.isRunning)

        mixer.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024, format: fmt) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
            // 8kHz buffers!
            print(buffer.format)
        }
    }catch {
        //print("An error occurred \(error)")
        return
    }

}
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you really mean 441Khz or actually 44.1 khz?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated answer** this answer used to try to rate convert with taps and mixers, which does not work.

You can use an `AVAudioConverter` to do rate conversion on the `AVAudioEngine` `inputNode`:

```
let engine = AVAudioEngine()

func setup() {
    let input = engine.inputNode
    let bus = 0
    let inputFormat = input.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: true)!

    let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat)!

    input.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: inputFormat) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        var newBufferAvailable = true

        let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
            if newBufferAvailable {
                outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                newBufferAvailable = false
                return buffer
            } else {
                outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                return nil
            }
        }

        let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!

        var error: NSError?
        let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
        assert(status != .error)

        // 8kHz buffers!
        print(convertedBuffer.format)
    }

    try! engine.start()
}
```

Comment: thx for the good answer but nothing changed.....i stil gets the buffer with 4100 Hz.
i checked the input format from the mixer and it is still 4100 Hz.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: i have now this error : 
kAudioUnitErr_TooManyFramesToProcess : inFramesToProcess=1024, mMaxFramesPerSlice=768

Comment: I don't no i have just the the print(buffer.format)
i think the error is coming from mixer.installTap because with 44100 and 16000 Hz is working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129171/discussion-between-steve-john-and-rhythmic-fistman).

Comment: @Rhythmic Fistman I read some comments on github that we can not set a sample rate different than then the device. I got excited when I saw your code, but couldnt make it work. Can I use it with AKPlayer? I dont use AvAudioEgine

Comment: I've never used AKPlayer, but you can definitely use `AVAudioConverter` to easily do sample rate conversion. Now that I look at it, I think that converter code should have a flag to stop `AVAudioConverterInputBlock` returning the same buffer more than once.

Comment: @ Rhythmic Fistman I am trying your code now. indeed "convertedBuffer" has the new sample rate but I lose the data in "buffer"? How convertedBuffer supposed to have the data? its just newly created? Also the "inputCallback" and "converter" is never used, what s the purpose of those? THANKS

Comment: Huh this answer is missing a line. Where did that go? Let me fix it.

Comment: Fixed it, I don't know how this answer was accepted.

Comment: What is fmt here ?

Comment: I don’t see anything called fmt in this answer. Can you be more specific?